# To select the first row out of multiple rows with consequential rise of a variable over time in R?

Tags: r, lag, rolling-computation

My dataset is furnished below.

I want to select the ID and the time which marks the start of three subsequent consequential rises in the PSA by at least 0.05. So in the example dataset, that I have used, I would like to extract the ID 2 with time 18 (because in the three subsequent time points there was a consequential rise in PSA and the difference between the PSA values at sequential timepoints are more than 0.05). I would really appreciate any prompt help.

| ID | time | psa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1.53 |
| 1 | 12 | 0.61 |
| 1 | 18 | 0.24 |
| 1 | 24 | 0.20 |
| 2 | 18 | 0.94 |
| 2 | 24 | 1.01 |
| 2 | 36 | 2.12 |
| 2 | 48 | 4.88 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.71 |
| 4 | 4 | 0.08 |
| 4 | 12 | 0.15 |
| 4 | 18 | 0.21 l |
| I 4 | 24 | 0.27 |
| 4 | 32 | 0.39 |

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I have modified my example. The data is in tabular format now. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach with `zoo::rollsum`.

For each `ID` subtract `psa` value with the previous `psa` value and create a flag which is `TRUE` if the difference is greater than 0.05. Count sum of next 3 such flags and select the row if all 3 rows are `TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(psa_increase = psa - dplyr::lag(psa) > 0.05) %>%
  filter(lead(zoo::rollsum(psa_increase, 3, align = 'left',fill = NA)) == 3) %>%
  select(-psa_increase)

#    ID  time   psa
#  <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     2    18  0.94
#2     4     4  0.08
#3     4    12  0.15
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), time = c(6L, 12L, 18L, 24L, 18L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 
2L, 4L, 12L, 18L, 24L, 32L), psa = c(1.53, 0.61, 0.24, 0.2, 0.94, 
1.01, 2.12, 4.88, 0.71, 0.08, 0.15, 0.21, 0.27, 0.39)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The row that I would have liked to select is time 18 for ID 2 and time 4 for ID 4. How will I get them? Please help. And could you please explain what rollsum function does here?

Comment: @Biostats `rollsum` performs rolling calculation and calculates sum for the window size. See this simple example : `rollsum(1:10, 3)` might help. I also updated the answer to make it closer to your expected output.